# How can I smooth this object?

Tags: modeling, mesh, objects

I have tried shade smooth but it completely torques the object into a weird shape, I tried the subdivision surface modifier but it does the same thing. Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: The first solution that comes to mind is to section it in  small slices, smooth them individualy and then rejoin them. I hope my suggestion will help you

Comment: You have to use loop cuts in order to "resharp" the angles as you can see in this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QMBrg4EKpcM

Comment: In the video the person uses "Shade Smooth" When I do that my object looks torqued

Comment: Go to the **Object Data** tab, expand the **Normals** section and turn on **Auto-Smooth**.

Comment: After shade smooth, he uses the loop cuts.

Comment: Thank you electric_Wizard that fixed it.